# Xamarin Forms Maps - Custom Renderer with Delegates - Map.VisibleRegion not updated

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms and Xamarin Form Maps 1.3.1.6296 in an iPad application.

I am trying to customize the annotation view that is shown when the user taps on the Pin. In order to do that, it seems that I need to implement a custom renderer, and in the custom renderer I can use a delegate to define the GetViewForAnnotation method to return the view the way I want to.

It kind of works, but when I use it the Map.VisibleRegion is not populated anymore. So I think I am missing something in the implementation of the delegate (or hit a bug).

So, the question is: **how do I get the Map.VisibleRegion to update?.**

I have forked Xamarin's official sample and made minimal modifications to show the problem, you can see commit [here](https://github.com/josea/xamarin-forms-samples/commit/c79f76ecd2bfe41dadc29043d8e85655e1fccd66)

In any case, my custom renderer is:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof( Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map), typeof(MobileCRM.iOS.ExtendedMapRenderer))]

namespace MobileCRM.iOS
{
    public class ExtendedMapRenderer : MapRenderer
    {
        public class MyMapViewDelegate : MKMapViewDelegate
        {
            public override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation (MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
            {
                var pin = new MKPinAnnotationView (annotation, "pin");
                pin.PinColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.Green;

                return pin; 
                //return null;
            }
        }

        private MKMapView _map { get { return Control as MKMapView; } } 

        public ExtendedMapRenderer() :base()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e); 

            if (_map != null) {
                // Comment/uncomment this line will change if the Map.VisibleRegion property is set or not.
                // ... that doesn't make sense.
                _map.Delegate = new MyMapViewDelegate (); 
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And in the Map Page I added this code to show the issue:

```
var btn = new Button () { Text = "Visible region" };
btn.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
     Debug.WriteLine ( "Map.VisibleRegion is null or not, depending if the delegate is set or not in the custom renderer");
     Debug.WriteLine ( String.Format("Is Map.VisibleRegion set? = {0} ", 
                    map.VisibleRegion == null ? "no" : "yes"));
     Debug.WriteLine ("See ExtendedMapRenderer.cs in the iOS project");
};
stack.Children.Add (btn);
```

Comment: Have you got any solution to this? I am stuck with visibleRegion being null.